# Type mismatch when passing tuple

Tags: f#

The following function accepts a list, a tuple (a, b) where 'a' is a tuple of  floats and a query to test against.

checkDist is a function that takes two tuples of floats and returns the distance between all points.

Now, my problem is that I run into a type missmatch error and cannot figure out why. It seems to type infer 'a' as only a single float, rather than float * float.

```
let intoTp lst (a, b) qry = 
   let rec intoTpLoop lst prevMax =
      match lst with
      | [] -> []
      | (feat, value) :: t ->
         let curr = checkDist feat qry    // current max
         let prev = checkDist prevMax qry // prev max

         // Check to replace top
         if prev < curr then
            let nextMax = (feat, value)
            prevMax :: intoTpLoop t nextMax
         else
            (feat, value) :: intoTpLoop t prevMax

   intoTpLoop lst (a, b)
```

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you are calling `checkDist` twice, the first time you pass `feat` which is a single value, the second time you pass `prevMax` which is a tuple. There is your contradiction.

When in doubt about what is happening with the type inference it helps to add type annotations to clarify what is supposed to be what (to the inference engine, to yourself and to us).

Comment: Both feat and prevMax, when passed to checkDist, are of val float * float. feat is not a single value, it is a tuple of floats.

Comment: if `feat` is a tuple then `prevMax :: intoTpLoop t nextMax` is missing the `value` part

Comment: I suppose that the problem is here: `| (feat, value) :: t ->` It should be `| feat :: t ->`

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem was that feat and prevMax was passed as the same type to checkDist, but then I used them differently when building the resulting list.